# Ubuntu 20.04 and Ubuntu Budgie 20.04 dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, ubuntu-budgie

What is procedure to install Ubuntu 20.04 and Ubuntu Budgie 20.04 on different partitions on same hard disk?
Please help

Comment: There are already 16,634 questions questions on this site that deal with dual boot. I am sure what you need must already have been asked and answered. Feel free to browse through them.

Comment: please take a look at the related Q&A on the right side of this page or do a search on top of this page.

Comment: Which ever is last install is the one whose grub will be in control. You must of course install in same boot mode, or both UEFI with newer systems on gpt partitioned drives. Grub will update to boot other install, but issues with os-prober security has grub turning off os-prober. If second install not found you may need to turn os-prober back on or create your own boot stanza in 40_custom. Do not share /home, but you can share data. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting